# Rails nested attributes callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, callback, nested-attributes

Right now I'm working on a Rails app that has an `Event` model and this model has `Category` models as nested attributes.

My `Event` model has a `state` attribute which must change to certain value if it's nested categories reach a particular amount.

I tried to do this using the `after_update` callback in the `Event` model, but it didn't work. Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Why it didn't work? Probably because it reached maximal recursion level.
Try something like this:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :category_count_state_updated
  has_many :categories
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :categories
  attr_accessible :categories_attributes
  after_update :update_state

  private
    def update_state
      unless self.category_count_state_updated
        self.state = 'categories_count_reached' if self.categories.count == 5
        self.category_count_state_updated = true
        self.save
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but actually when testing this, I put a debugger inside the 'update_state' method but it does not stop there. Don't know why really.

If I save the event model in the test and not insite that method, then it works, but it is not a good practice. Any idea?

Thanks again!

Comment: Well... is this callback never called or it is called only when you change at least one field of parent model? Maybe try changing this callback into `after_save` as this also may be your case.

Comment: Ok, I fixed this but did it another way. I added the after_update callback inside nested model. When after_update is executed, it notifies it's parent (event model) and everything works great. Thanks anyway Maciej!

Cheers,
Martin